# Reverting CiviCRM on Drupal 7 to last backed up state?

Tags: drupal, backups

What is the best procedure for reverting the CiviCRM, powered by Drupal 7, back to a previous backed up state, in case of database corruption, failed upgrades or other undesirable changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**How to revert the CiviCRM to previous state:**

1. Put Drupal into maintenance mode
2. Disable integration modules
3. Replace `civicrm.settings.php` with backed up copy and check permissions
4. Remove everything in `<drupal_home>/sites/all/modules/civicrm` and
   replace with backed up version and check permissions
5. Drop civicrm database and import backup database
6. Clear caches and empty `<drupal_home>sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c` and check permissions
7. Re-enable integration modules
8. Log in, test and debug

**Command Line Cheatsheet for Drush and MySQL, Regarding These Steps:**

Maintenance mode: `drush vset maintenance_mode 1`

Disabling and Enabling CiviCRM Integration Modules:

`drush pm-disable [integration_module]` or
`drush pm-enable [integration_module]`

Dropping, re-creating and importing a database in MySQL:

```
mysql -u [username] -p
use [database name];
DROP DATABASE [database];
CREATE DATABASE [database];
source path/to/backup.sql;
```

Clear caches: `drush cc all`

Dealing with templates_c: `rm <drupal_home>sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/*`